# Dynamically creating WrapPanel buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, data-binding, wrappanel

I have a table storing purchased items and the entity class using in NHibernate:

```
public class PurchasedItem
{
    public virtual int Id          { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual int SortSale    { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to reduce the code duplication by getting all records from the `PurchasedItems` table (`IList <PurchasedItem>` object). Records have been sorted in descending order by `SortSale` column. What's the best way of creating `WrapPanel` buttons based on the `IList <PurchasedItem>` object? I would like to assign the event handler for each button as well. The button displays a title with the name of the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a listbox using a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanel.  In XAML you can do the following:

```
<ListBox Name="MyList" ItemsSource={StaticResource YourList}>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="40" MinWidth="40" Content="{Binding Id}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In this example, I assume YourList is a list of PurchasedItem's.  You can also set the ItemsSource from code (ie: MyList.ItemsSource = YourList;).  When you click the Button, it'll call the following which can display a messagebox containing whatever you need:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((sender as Button).DataContext as PurchasedItem).Product.Name);
    }
```

Note that I set the Content of the Button to the Id of the PurchasedItem so you'll probably want to change that.